# Fork a JVM in a Leiningen project

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, integration, leiningen

Is it possible to fork a VM in a Leiningen project, similarly to Ant's  task when the fork="true" option is enabled?

I can get around this with scripts, but it would be very useful to simply write "lein run" and have two processes start. It's also possible to import (or worse, write) code to do this, but in this case it's much more appropriate to have in the build environment.

Comment: Any chance you could just use a task executor or thread pool?

Comment: No, it's not my application that I need to run, but it does need to be available to connect to. I *had* taken the approach of running it in another thread (and it worked), but the logging framework of the other application required such hideous workarounds that it was clear I was on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want [lein-daemon](https://github.com/arohner/lein-daemon)